# change username on elementary OS properly

Tags: command-line, user

How to change `username` on elementary OS — e.g. `linux@eos` to `dago@eos` properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been answered in [another question on another StackExchange site](https://askubuntu.com/a/34075/422035) but this is basically what you need to do:

While the user you need to modify is logged out and you're logged in as another sudoer user, do the following:

```
sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername
```

This changes your username but not your home folder. If you're okay with having a different home folder name from your username, you're pretty much done. Otherwise, refer to the linked answer for more details.